# Can I Add Stack Into an ArrayList (or Linked List)?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I need to convert every line of a CSV file into separated Stack(One stack per Line).My problem is after I scan through each line and convert the CSV into stack, where should i store the stack? I dont know how many stack i am going to create so i need a dynamic data structure to store the created stack. Below is my code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(filepath));
Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();
String line;        
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                          line = scanner.nextLine();
                          List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(":",-1));
                             String x=items.get(0);
         while(x == null || x.equals("#"))
                       {
                         line = scanner.nextLine();
                         items=Arrays.asList(line.split(":",-1));
                         x=items.get(0);
                       }`

            st.addAll(items);
            //i need to store st into a data structure before i clear it.
            st = new Stack<String>();
            }
```

Comment: Are you asking whether to choose an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`? Or are you asking whether there can be a list of stacks in general?

Comment: Why don't you try? What makes you think you can't store Stacks into a List?

Comment: `List<Stack<String>> stackList = new ArrayList<Stack<String>>()` is what you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation you are looking for:

```
              String line;        
              while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                                  line = scanner.nextLine();
                                  List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(":",-1));
                                     String x=items.get(0);
                 while(x == null || x.equals("#"))
                               {
                                 line = scanner.nextLine();
                                 items=Arrays.asList(line.split(":",-1));
                                 x=items.get(0);
                               }`

                    st.addAll(items);
                    stackList.add(st);

                    //i need to store st into a data structure before i clear it.
                    st = new Stack<String>();
                    }
```

But, It is not recommended that this be the platform for such problems that might be solved by a simple google search or a little basic study.

Answer (score -1):

Please specify your language and which libraries you are using.
However indenting your code right is even more important.
This is what I think youre after anyway:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(filepath));
List<Stack<String>> st = new List<Stack<String>>();
String line;        
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
     line = scanner.nextLine();
     List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(":",-1));
     String x = items.get(0);

     if (x != null && !x.equals("#"))
         st.add(items);
}
```

What I can tell there is no need to have a 'dynamic datastructure' at least when having not too large files like over 50 Mb.

Comment: But, i need to store the st value to another place(or class) for later use.

Comment: Then you can use your st to do that after these lines of code.